# Matlab: Is there a command to set 'code folding' preference?

Tags: matlab, command, settings, folding

I'm using the %% command to split my code into blocks for the sake of readability,
I collapse those blocks when i'm not working in them.
The default settings don't give you the ability to fold them, so my first question is:

Can you tweak this setting by command, so anyone who opens my script has the option to fold them?

My second question is: Can I program my code to set the blocks as collapsed by default?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't believe that this is possible programmatically. Even if it was/is, I would strongly suggest against modifying the MATLAB preferences of any user who used your code.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed possible

1) Type `preference` in the command window to get up the preferences menu (or you find in under **home**)

2) Go to Editor/Debugger -> Code Folding

3) Mark the enable box for **Sections**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I actually meant to auto-check the 'Code Folding' in preferences by commmand, at the beginning of my script. That would have as consequence; anyone who opens my script can fold the blocks. Best would be if those blocks are already on collapsed state, too.

Comment: So the command would be something like: `preferences editor (codefolding = 1);`

Comment: I have not heard about such. Preferences are easy to set anyway. However, have you ever got any complaints about this? It is my belief that people normally does what they feel is most convenient for them. That means that if they have a problem with code folding they open up preferences and fix it. Also not all person wants default code folding. I feel it is hard to find variables spanning multiple blocks. If you have so long functions you need code folding of sections I would advise to keep the functions shorter. However, it is not for me to judge and if you want to code folding so use it.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap your sections in the following way:

```
%% //Section header
for folding=true

%// Your code here

end %//folding
```

This allows you to fold on the `for` "loop".

It will work for everybody who has a fairly recent Matlab editor, without messing with editor settings.

Note that you should not have an actual variable named `folding`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is entirely possible:

```
com.mathworks.services.Prefs.setBooleanPref('EditorMCodeFoldEnabledcell', true);
```

The command takes effect immediately. Find more information in the article [Changing system preferences programmatically](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/changing-system-preferences-programmatically).